# Rails: prevent a css file from being added to asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

We're accessing a 3rd-party iFrame (dialog) in our web app. This is loaded by javascript and served via the 3rd-party's server. If we provide them with a link to a custom CSS file we can change the appearance of the dialog.

How, in the Rails pipeline, can we create this file and then provide the 3rd-party with a URL that will, hopefully, respect (read: use) our CDN?

Does the file belong in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/`? I'm pretty sure that becomes part of asset pipeline as well...

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you put it in /public/assets? That should be accessible from the outside, if I understand what you're asking.